# Spring Cloud Stream Consumer Load Balancing Strategy

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

As per the Spring Cloud Stream documentation:

> When there are multiple consumer instances bound with the same group name, then messages are load-balanced across those consumer instances so that each message sent by a producer is consumed by only a single consumer instance within each group.

I would like to understand the Load Balancing Strategy used in this context. Also, would like to understand how does the load balancing on consumers are impacted with the use of the below properties,

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency
spring.cloud.stream.<binder>.bindings.input.consumer.prefetch
```

The binder in our case is RabbitMQ.

Our consumer application is just a pass through and does not have any significant logic. Our payload is plain text message with ~2 KB Size. The load produced to the consumer for processing is 10K messages.

When we have the below configurations and with up to 4 or 5 instances of the consumers running,

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency=10
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.prefetch=5
```

The load seems to be evenly distributed, but when we start increasing the instances beyond 5, the distribution is not so even, i.e., one of these instances start to receive more load while other instances are idle or just does not share the load equally.

However, if we start reducing the concurrency and prefetch values, we start seeing some even distribution among the instances i.e., with the below properties and with up to 10 instances, we observe even distribution.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.concurrency=2
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.prefetch=1
```

Having the `instanceCount` and `instanceIndex` properties, does not seem to yield desired results.

```
spring.cloud.stream.instanceCount
spring.cloud.stream.instanceIndex
```

Though, we understand these `instanceCount` and `instanceIndex` properties makes more sense in a partitioned environment. Since RabbitMQ is not naturally partitioned we might not be seeing the difference.

It looks like we should be able to add custom partition strategy in our producers to split the load across queues with RabbitMQ. However, we will have to alter our payload structure to introduce such a strategy.

But, before that, we would like to understand that if there would be an efficient way to do load balancing by just using an optimal value in the consumer properties.

Comment: AMQP (and thereby RabbitMQ) uses round robin load balancing between consumers. I'm a little bit unsure if I followed your setup, so from a RabbitMQ stand point it would be helpful to see how many unacked messages are in the system while the uneven load balancing is seen.

Comment: Thank you!! Your comment lead us to catch the root cause. We did not see any unacknowledged messages in RabbitMQ. But, there is a common cache system that consumer instances connect during startup and use the cache while processing without any significant business logic. We identified a threading issue here, each threads were creating new cache connections  instead of using a pooled connection. Threads were getting blocked because of this and the whole processing was impacted. After we corrected this, we see an even load-balancing of messages across all consumer instances.